# Show all branchs history with child branchs

Tags: git, branch

I am searching for a way to visualize all branch in remote (with git) in a single time, like on this image, even if some branchs don't have any commit.
[image]

But when I run gitk command, I obtain something like this :

[image]

On this image, it looks like master is child of dev, and the feature branchs are on the same level, and if master had no commit, it would have look like if master and dev are same the branch.

Is there a way to display the branchs history in a clearer way like on the schema ? All the solutions I have found give the same result as the gitk.

Comment: Every dot, the yellow or the blue small circle, is a commit. Along with the line downwards, the next dot is a parent. The `dev` dot and the `master` dot are diverged, they are siblings.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, dev is not child of master ?

Comment: Starting from the `master` dot, it needs to turn and go upwards to reach the `dev` dot. So no, it's not. The same, starting from the `dev` dot, it needs to go down first and then turn and go upwards to reach the `master` dot. So, `master` is not `dev`'s child either.

Comment: okay, is that normal in git or did I wrongly create the branchs ? (I would like dev to be master's child). And is there a way to show branchs in one vertical line per branch like on the schema ?

Comment: It's quite normal to have diverged branches. If you'd like `dev` to be a child of `master` in your case, you can run `git rebase master dev`. But it seems  `dev` has been pushed to the remote repository. `git rebase` would change the history of `dev`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! And if I would like to keep some branchs siblings, is there a way to separate vertical line for each "family" ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "child" or a "sibling" branch in git.  Although trying to be helpful, ElpieKay is leading you down a road to confusion.  I doubt the two of you even mean the same thing when you say "child of master"

Comment: The reason you think of `master` as "looking like the child" in the above diagram is that `master` is drawn to the right.  This is arbitrary.  If you rebase as ElpieKay suggests, it won't matter; eventually the branches will again diverge and it will again be arbitrary which appears "to the right".

Comment: Also, while ElpieKay gave a brief warning that rebasing would alter history, they didn't explain the implications.  This is not a "quick fix" (even if it would ultimately do what you want); rebasing when commits have been pushed requires that every user of the repo coordinate to "recover" from the bad state it puts things in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** - A few notes added at the end, as comments suggest a bit more information might help.

---

The problem is that you're trying to impose concepts on git that don't exist in git.

There is no such thing as a "branch with no commits".  A commit doesn't "belong to a branch".  A branch is not a "child" of another branch.  No tool can look at a repository and, based on the information there, draw an intuitive graph aligned with these concepts, because these concepts are not to be found in the information kept in a repo.

In git a branch is a type of ref.  A ref is a pointer to a commit.

When you say "branch with no commits", you mean "someone was on branch `a` and created a new branch `b`; but nobody has yet committed while on branch `b`".  `git` doesn't know that's what happened; what git knows is that the branch ref for `b` points to a commit that's reachable from `a`.  In many cases that means `b` and `a` point to the same commit.

The type of diagram you want is drawn with the notion that every commit can be uniquely assigned to a branch.  In `git` a commit is either reachable from, or not reachable from, any given ref.  (Reachable means that you can find the commit by first looking at the commit the ref points to, and then possibly following the parent pointers on commits.)  A commit can therefore be reachable from many branches at the same time.  Often the "root" commit is reachable from *all* branches.  If you are on branch `a` and you create branch `b`, then all the commits reachable from branch `a` are also reachable from branch `b`.

When you think of a branch `b` as a "child" of another branch `a`, you mean that someone was on `a` when they created `b`.  This is not something git keeps track of.  It is impossible to tell whether `a` was created from `b`, or `b` was created from `a`, or both `a` and `b` were created from some other branch.

If you strictly follow a set of conventions for how you branch and merge, then you could conceivably create a tool that interprets the branch/commit topology assuming those conventions to produce something like you want.  How useful this is may depend on how realistic it is to think that you'd never have to violate your conventions.  I don't know of any such tools, and since they would work in terms of fictitious concepts that don't matter to git I'm not sure how useful it would be in practice anyway.

The sample diagram you have comes form a document describing a particular branching practice.  That practice imposes some of the concepts (like child branches), so it makes sense to describe the *ideal* of that practice using that type of chart.  But in a *real* repo, that's just not how things look.

**UPDATE STARTS HERE**

In comments you mention that you can't tell what branch a given commit was made on.  In general this is correct, because that is not a thing that is tracked in git.  You can tell from what branch(es) a commit is reachable, because that's all git knows - and *sometimes* that allows you to infer what branch it was created on.

But you mention not seeing separation between the branches, and that got me thinking.  In your `gitk` diagram there just *isn't* much separation between the branches.  And probably that's caused by the use of "fast-forward" merges, which - for better or worse - is a default behavior of git even though it can be very confusing.

Suppose I start working in a repo that has a single commit, and `master` and `dev` branches.

```
X <--(master)(dev)
```

Now, I start working on the dev branch.  I create a few commits.

```
X <--(master)
 \
  A -- B -- C <--(dev)
```

Now, I merge to master.  By default git sees that it can take a shortcut, by just updating the `master` ref to point at `C`.  This is called a fast-forward.

```
X -- A -- B -- C <--(dev)(master)
```

If we think only about the content that's "current" on `master`, this shortcut got us the correct result.  But some facts about history are lost.  We can prevent this if, instead of just saying `git merge dev`, we say

```
git merge --no-ff dev
```

If you're using a branch strategy that gives meaning to the branch topology, you almost always should use `--no-ff` when merging.  This would yield

```
X ----------- M<--(master)
 \           /
  A -- B -- C <--(dev)
```

and the graph you'd see in `gitk` will probably be more agreeable to you (though it still won't look quite like what you see in the diagrams you refer to).

Comment: so there is no way to display history like on the chart ? I really find gitk history unreadable, I don't know on which branch where made commits and where is the separation between branchs, and i can't make the differences between the branches. But every git tutorial show the same schema : one line per branch with a link if branchs have been merged/separated. Even in git documentation

Comment: I'll update to clarify a few things, but basically your first statement is correct.  While gitk-type graphs take some getting used to, they *are* readable with a bit of practice - but I'm suspecting something else is causing some of the confusion, so please do look through the updates once I've added them.

Comment: thanks for all ! (I didn't understand why the branch vanished when i merged)